# Ask for Notification permission After sign up (not just after app starts)

Tags: ios, push-notification, swift2

can we  change the default behaviour of Permission seeking method (it appears when we launch the app ) but i want to show it when user is signed up  , i'm doing this in my appDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(
        forTypes: [.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], categories: nil)


    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

    return true
}
```

Comment: You can call this from your `viewdidload` of home screen or whatever you displayed after signed up screen!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can place it in different classes where you want to ask user like below

```
let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(
            forTypes: [.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], categories: nil)

UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
```

Comment: its not going to make any problem right ? and it'll only appear once until user provides his decision ??

Comment: Yes, it appear once